# Cannot Call addSubLayer:

Tags: ios, calayer, quartz-core

I am trying to add a gradient to my view and am adding the following to drawRect:

```
CAGradientLayer *g = [[CAGradientLayer alloc]init];
g.frame = self.bounds;
g.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor],
            [[UIColor redColor] CGColor], nil];
g.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                nil];
[self addSubLayer:g];
```

I receive the warning: No visible @interface declares the selector 'addSubLayer:'

although I imported the Quartz Core framework since CALayer is part of it (otherwise I would have already received an error when I initialized the CAGradientLayer).
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, this silly question, but are you doing this from within a subclassed UIView? Or from the view controller? What is the class of `self`?

Comment: Good question. It is from within a subclassed UIView, not from the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that line should be (note capitalization and the use of `self.layer`):

```
[self.layer addSublayer:g];
```

[`addSublayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/addSublayer%3a) is a `CALayer` instance method, not a `UIView` instance method.